# Maven cxf Plugin error

Tags: maven, cxf, pom.xml, maven-plugin, cxf-codegen-plugin

Why am I seeing this error in my `pom.xml` file when I'm adding the apache cxf plugin?

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.5.4:wsdl2java (execution: generate-sources, phase: generate-sources)

Answer (score 5):

Or move to 2.6.3/2.7.0 that has the M2E lifecylce stuff embedded in it so there is no need for the connector.   That also has the benefit of wiring warnings and such coming from the code generation right into the eclipse warning systems.

2.7.1-SNAPSHOT has a bunch of other fixes related to the m2e things as well.

Comment: Does not seem like it is published, the last version is 2.6.0

Comment: Sorry, I meant 2.6.3/2.7.0 which are both in central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/cxf/cxf-codegen-plugin/

Comment: Do you expect to have the same updates for cxf-xjc-plugin, xsdtojava target?

Comment: You said "lifecycle stuff embedded in it so there is no need for the connector" 

Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700014/automatic-wsdl-java-stub-generation-in-eclipse-workspace-using-apache-cxf-and-cx?noredirect=1#comment55254861_33700014 

the stubs aren't generating automatically for me. am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install m2e-cxf-codegen-connector from [here](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2e-cxf-codegen-connector/). Also you may have a problem with latest versions of Eclipse, so please also check this [issue](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2e-cxf-codegen-connector/issues/detail?id=1).

Comment: this post is from 2012. i am trying to get latest eclipse to use this. since then this project went out of google code support. how does one do this now?

Comment: Daniel is right, you do not need to download connector anymore, it is all embedded. Check version of m2e you use

Comment: I have my eclipse set up with this and there are no maven errors about the lifecycle but there are no sources generated when running eclipse build.

Comment: Check that plugin is not ignored in Preferences / Maven / Lifecycle Mappings globally or locally in pom.xml

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700014/automatic-wsdl-java-stub-generation-in-eclipse-workspace-using-apache-cxf-and-cx?noredirect=1#comment55254861_33700014 the stubs aren't generating automatically for me i show a screenshot where the lifecycle is not ignored