# Automatic WSDL Java Stub generation in Eclipse Workspace using Apache CXF and CXF Maven Plugin

Tags: eclipse, cxf

I am using Apache CXF 2.x, Eclipse Luna 64-bit, Maven 3.x

I have a single web service producer app that has a WSDL and I want the Stubs in the app to generate dynamically from the WSDL.

I have installed the Maven Lifecycle Dependency and installed both M2E WTP connectors. In Eclipse Project -> Properties -> Maven -> Lifecycle Mapping, I see cxf-codegen-plugin:wsdl2java and it shows that it is properly attached to the generate-sources lifecycle phase.

[image: lifecycle looks fine]

When I run `mvn install` manually, the stubs are generated automatically and everything works fine.

But if I clean the maven project and load it in eclipse, eclipse does not automatically generate the stubs. I see Java missing class errors in Eclipse workspace showing the gen is not occurring.

What step am I missing?

Here is the POM that I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
      xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>testWeb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>testWeb</name>

    <properties>
        <cxf.version>2.1.3</cxf.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>ILP Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://dhud001.test.com:8675/maven_snapshot/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>       
        <repository>
            <id>eclipse</id>
            <name>Eclipse</name>
            <url>https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/gen/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <useCompileClasspath>true</useCompileClasspath> <!-- if you don't use this, the soapui test bundle will cause classloading issues with this plugin. -->
                            <sourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/gen/java</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/wsdl/TestService.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/TestService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-all</extraarg>
                                                                                </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>                            
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>               
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I was able to install Build helper maven connector and also tried to install https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2e-cxf-codegen-connector/ as well. But the sources continue to not generate.

Example eclipse project that can reproduce the problem is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vlo0ghbmkplu7au/service.zip?dl=0

Comment: Have you asked on the cxf-users mailing list yet?

Comment: I'll look into that it's tricky to sign up and stuff.

Comment: There is probably some undocumented flag you have to set, like
`-Dm2e.cxf.actually.work.this.time=true`
or something.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me why I switched to IntelliJ, JAX-WS RI codegen where it's enough, Axis2 where it's not enough, and only do the dependencies and actual compile/jar/war/ejb/ear stuff using Maven.

Comment: it's definitely not some flag. i think it is something about the newer versions of jars conflicting with the old way it worked. perhaps MyEclipse has tackled this correctly?

Comment: @David I emailed the cxf list too. And I opened a ticket with MyEclipse because their software is also affected by the bug maybe they can help me fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the "Update Maven Projects" to trigger the cxf stubs to be rebuilt from Eclipse you need to open the `target` folder and delete `target/*`. Then hit `alt + f5 + enter` and your stubs will refresh.

For some reason manually cleaning the target folder contents triggers maven's cxf build to generate the stubs. Changing the WSDL/deleting the contents of your generated sources src folder do **not** help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you were expecting in what circumstances but there appears to be a problem with the lifecycle mapping for the cxf m2e plugin, in that the clean mechanism isn't cleaning target folders appropriate to that plugin.

So, just delete the target folder manually (or at least delete the "cxf-codegen-plugin-markers" sub-folder) and then run a build. This should get the java files generated where needed.

You can also execute maven goals via the Run or Debug context menu items. Maven does delete the whole "target" folder on clean. So running a clean and an install from the context run menu (or from a maven run configuration) would also do what you need.

Note that command line maven didn't like your "cxf" dependency and it doesn't appear to be needed, anyway. I had to delete it to get this to work.

One last thing, the cxf plugin is also not refreshing the project after an eclipse build, which is needed to see what is generated in the build. So a quick F5 on the eclipse project is needed after a build.

Comment: Hi Tony. Thanks for taking the time to answer. I already am able to run the mvn clean/install from Eclipse and it creates the stubs. That was never the problem. The problem is that when I make a change to the WSDL, i expected Eclipse to automatically detect that change, generate the stubs in the src/gen/java folder, and presto you'll see the change in your workspace. This is not happening. I have to manually run mvn install each time to get the updates to the stubs to occur. Very annoying and time consuming because we change our WSDL a *lot*.

Comment: OK, Nicholas. I got a different message from your main question. It looks like the cxf m2e connector hasn't got the lifecycle mapping quite right. You may be able to correct that in your pom, by replacing the null execute element of the lifecycleMappingMetadata section (which is only in your sample project, not the pom given in the question) with: 

`<execute>
 <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
  </execute>
`
In principle, this should run the goal for incremental builds.

Comment: awarded you 100+ bounty for your help. thanks again. see the answer that i eventually found on complete accident below. total dumb luck that i figured it out

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas. I didn't spend a lot of time on this but did manage to get it to run on a WSDL change, once, after adding that runOnIncremental property to the pom, though it didn't seem to run a second time. It may take a little more investigation to find out exactly what works.